# Saving dataframe to hive ( how to change df schema types to string if its of type date , i do not want to hardcode columns names)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to covert pandas df to spark df and save it to hive.

```
    #create spark df from panda dataframe
    df = self.ss.createDataFrame(dataframe)

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_Template") 
    self.ss.sql("create table IF NOT EXISTS database."+ table_name +" STORED AS PARQUET as select * from table_Template")
```

ERROR:
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: **Parquet does not support date. See HIVE-6384**;

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, to cast all `date` type columns to `string`.

```
df.select(map(lambda field: F.col(field.name).cast("string") if field.dataType.typeName == "date" else F.col(field.name), df.schema)).show()
```